# I can't start my Moto G60 anymore after locking the bootloader

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, fastboot, bootloader-lock, motorola

I recently downgraded my Android on Moto G60 (I downloaded ROM from some websites) because my phone screen was sometimes not working which upon locking and unlocking the phone made the screen work again, so I thought downgrading might help. The phone was working fine until a few weeks ago when I had to restart the phone for some reason and the phone was showing that the bootloader was unlocked and the phone's sensitive data might be attacked if I didn't lock it.

[image]

> No valid operating system could be found.
> The device will not boot.
>
> For more information, visit our support forum:
> support.motorola.com

I watched a tutorial on YouTube and connected my phone to my PC and then proceeded to lock the bootloader. After that, I tried to restart my phone, but it didn't start anymore and it shows this on the screen. The recovery mode doesn't work and also I tried to unlock the bootloader once again but I couldn't. I tried to use Rescue and Smart Assistant, but it says "The connected device does not match the shipping software values expected and Rescue cannot run". I took my phone to a service center and they said that they couldn't help me.

(P.S. My phone is not rooted)

Answer (score 1):

A locked bootloader only accepts a correctly signed OS image. For the same hardware there can be multiple OS images which each signed by a different key. So just replacing the OS image might have worked, if you had left the bootloader unlocked.

Without working recovery you can try to get to bootloader mode and re-unlock the phone and hope OEM unlock setting is still active (which is usually not because unlocking the bootloader has reset user data and thus reset OEM unlock to disabled).

**If that doesn't work your device can be considered bricked.**

Relocking the bootloader without being 100% sure to know what you are doing is one of the actions that has a good chance to brick a device as a locked bootloader only boots correct unmodified OS.

Next time contact the vendor and wait for the next update to fix the problems. Installing a different OS image and re-locking the bootloader is something even experienced users are afraid of because of the high risk to brick the phone.

Comment: I tried oem unlocking with no succes. I guess my phone is bricked. Thank you for replying.